# i am having error with the code in pyspark related with df.withcolumn

Tags: pyspark

Can I use the following code:

```python
df.withColumn("id", df["id"].cast("integer")).na.drop(subset=["id"])
```

If `id` is not a valid integer, it will be NULL and dropped in the subsequent step.

Without changing the type

```python
df = sqlContext.read.text("sample.txt") 
df.select(
    df.value.substr(1.2).alias('id'),
    df.value.substr(3.13).alias('name'),
    df.value.substr(16,8).alias('date'),
    df.value.substr(24,3).alias('Yes/No')
).show()

valid = df.where(df["id"].cast("integer").isNotNull())
invalid = df.where(df["id"].cast("integer").isNull())
```

Here my `df.printschema` prints

> ```python
> root
> |-- value: string (nullable = true)
> ```

```python
+---+-------------+--------+------+
| id| name          | date |Yes/No| 
+---+-------------+--------+------+ 
| 01|abcdefghijklkm |010V2201| 9Ye| 
+---+-------------+--------+------+
| ab| abcdefghijklmm|010V2201| 9Ye| 
+---+-------------+--------+------+
```

this is a sample output

Expected result 
row with integer column to be removed with null or invalid values, can i use df.withcolumn into it ? if i can then how ?

Comment: I think you're asking: "Do I need to convert to integer before dropping nulls?" It depends on what your desired output would be- converting a string to integer can introduce new `null` values if the string can not be converted. A small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) with sample input and the desired output would be helpful in clearing up what you're asking, because it's unclear to me at the moment.

Comment: Hello Pault,this part of my code

df = sqlContext.read.text("sample.txt") 
df.select(
    df.value.substr(1.2).alias('id'),
    df.value.substr(3.13).alias('name'),
    df.value.substr(16,8).alias('date'),
    df.value.substr(24,3).alias('Yes/No')
).show()

this prints the txt file in Data frame


can i use any method to make sure that the column id will skip printing rows where there are no integer values in my string,

Comment: +---+-------------+--------+------+
| id|         name|    date|Yes/No|
+---+-------------+--------+------+
| 01| abcdefghijklkm|010V2201|   9Ye|
+---+-------------+--------+------+
| ab| abcdefghijklmm|010V2201|   9Ye|
+---+-------------+--------+------+


this is a sample output, i want the id column to not print those rows where id is not an integer 

i would the id c

Comment: Don't put code/data/output in the comments. [Edit] them into your question.

Comment: hello Pault, i have edited my question and put the sample output there